# Highmaps View data table - Export-data.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have created a map and trying to View data table. I am using export-data.js.
   It is giving me state names but not values.

Here is the link for the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmandava6442/tk2ndpt5/4/) I have created. Any help is appreciated.

```js
    var data = [{ "hc-key": "us-wa", "Value": 40389 }, { "hc-key": "us-wi", "Value": 25851 }, { "hc-key": "us-mi", "Value": 51140 }, { "hc-key": "us-ne", "Value": 8270 }, { "hc-key": "us-dc", "Value": 5346 }, { "hc-key": "us-ia", "Value": 11540 }, { "hc-key": "us-ky", "Value": 22285 }, { "hc-key": "us-nm", "Value": 16941 }, { "hc-key": "us-pa", "Value": 62291 }, { "hc-key": "us-id", "Value": 6287 }, { "hc-key": "us-ms", "Value": 12345 }, { "hc-key": "us-nd", "Value": 2124 }, { "hc-key": "us-az", "Value": 26028 }, { "hc-key": "us-md", "Value": 30335 }, { "hc-key": "us-sd", "Value": 2016 }, { "hc-key": "us-fl", "Value": 62238 }, { "hc-key": "us-ca", "Value": 94603 }, { "hc-key": "us-tx", "Value": 89376 }, { "hc-key": "us-ar", "Value": 4600 }, { "hc-key": "us-de", "Value": 1657 }, { "hc-key": "us-in", "Value": 10703 }, { "hc-key": "us-il", "Value": 14607 }, { "hc-key": "us-me", "Value": 1065 }, { "hc-key": "us-ma", "Value": 6693 }, { "hc-key": "us-va", "Value": 11208 }];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.seriesTypes.map.prototype.exportKey = 'name';

        //Highcharts.seriesTypes.map.prototype.exportValue = 'data';

        $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
            chart: {
                animation: true
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Map'
            },
            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'top'
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'map',
                data: data,
                color: '#25873a',
                joinBy: 'hc-key',
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
                name: 'States',
                states: {
                   
                    hover: {
                        color: '#BADA55'
                    }
                },

                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.properties.postal-code}'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:15px"> Count</span><br/>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="font-size:18px">{point.properties.postal-code}: {point.Value:,.0f}</span>'
                }
            }],
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Thanks,
   Naveen Mandava.

Comment: It looks like you wanted to add a link to a jsFiddle page displaying an example of the problem, but there is no link. Please edit the question so that more information is given on what you are trying to do and what outcomes you want.

See this link for more details on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value` instead of `Value` in your data.

**Fixed example:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/47gqc0wv/